# Adaptive hole filling in regards of the adjacent regions

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have the following problem, best explained with this picture:
[image]

I have a hole (blue) with an edge (white line).
I now want to fill the hole with the color of the region next to it.
So above the white line it shoud be yellow and below the white line red.

Is there an algorithm which does something similar i could adapt?
Possibly even an implementation in openCV?

EDIT
Ok, maybe to specify: The white line is from an edge detection and irregular. Also there are many blue spots like this on a big image and it needs to compute the color for each spot according to the adjacent colors

EDIT2: added a better example image containing the whole scene:
[image]
To further clarify: Only the blue "holes" should be filled, because they are the regions of error we know. The white object edges are taken from a ground truth for this example which is more precise than the data we can actually work with. It is possible to get a aproximation of that edge though.

The data is a depth map from a multi camera scan by the way. Goal is to fill the error regions cause by overshadowing of the objects. If an object can't be viewed by 2 camera views, because it is obfuscated, no depth estimation is possible.

Comment: why don't you just code it yourself? its quite straight forward... no need to adapt existing algorithms.

Comment: Do you know the equation of the white line? If so, it is indeed quite straightforward: just fill everything that are above the line with yellow, otherwise with red. If you don't know the equation of the white line, you will have to fit a line using the blue pixels.

Comment: Ok, maybe to specify: The white line is from an edge detection and irregular. Also there are many blue spots like this on a big image and it needs to compute the color for each spot according to the adjacent colors.

Comment: Please consider providing a better sample image so folks can better understand your needs - i.e one with an additional colour where all three colours meet at a point.

Comment: Is it right that **exclusively blue** pixels should be changed, and not any others that are apparently incorrectly coloured?

Comment: Yes, because the edges are taken from a ground truth for this example which is more precise than the data i can actually work with. It is possible to get a aproximation of that edge though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda found a solution to my problem: openCV has a [inpaint](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) function.
I'm gonna modify this according to [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6460564/). Should work fine for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Maye you want to have a look at the OpenCV's function called [floodFill](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga366aae45a6c1289b341d140839f18717).

This function has an *input mask parameter* that you could use to specify the white line between the two colored regions.

Comment: I think the problem is that the yellow area may have two, three or more other sides which each abutt another, different colour.